# Motherboard not detecting GPU, BIOS/Grub screen not showing, Ubuntu successfully loads and working with 1050TI

Tags: motherboard, bios, grub, gpu, nvidia

My specs:

```
GPU: NVIDIA GeForce 1050TI Palit
CPU: AMD Ryzen 9 5900X
RAM: HyperX Fury 32GB 3600MHz CL18 (HX436C18FB3/32) (Working at 3200MHz because of CPU maximum)
Motherboard: ASUS TUF GAMING X570-PRO (WI-FI)
Disks: M2 NVME Samsung 980 PRO 1TB + Samsung SATA 860 QVO 1TB
```

I didn't update BIOS/etc, everything is in the default, except I changed memory MHz to 3200, for some reason it was detected as 2400MHz.

The issue is that on motherboard there are 4 LEDs: RAM, CPU, BOOT, GPU. The GPU LED is on even after successful but, which means there is something wrong with GPU, but I am working perfectly fine with Ubuntu 21.04 OS with 2 monitors, and no issues detected.

But during boot there is no default BIOS screen, which says (Press F2 or Delete...), and after that on Linux distros there is a GRUB screen, which I cannot see as well. After some time, the system boots and shows Ubuntu 21.04 login screen.

P.S When I first setup my PC it was working fine, one thing I have done after setup is that I ejected my 3rd HDD drive from PC.

P.P.S bios/grub screens shows when I use my old Nvidia GTX 760.

Comment: That card  has 3 outputs, perhaps it is defaulting to the one you are not using.

Comment: @Bib, the LED on motherboard about GPU I guess doesn't care about outputs, it cares about internal GPU state or something.

Comment: The assumption is that your monitors are connected to the NV video card. Connect to the internal one, go into BIOS and tell it to prioritise the add-in card, or disable the onboard one.

Comment: This CPU has no internal GPU.